# Listener to determine fragment is no longer visible in view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I searched around...there are many questions to determine if a fragment becomes visible to user in a view pager

but I did not find a listener which determines if a fragment becomes invisible to the user for real

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the page Change Listener.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want to be able to get data from the previous page in order to save changes if the user  confirms changes

Comment: "I want a listener for that page to be invoked when completely moving to the next page and a message to display asking the user to whether he wants to save changes or not", here is what you are asking, a listener when the user leaves the page, you never mentioned that you wanted to get data.

Comment: You can get current page in ViewPager so you can also get the previous page (index - 1). Also the previous page will still be loaded in a ViewPager until you move to a further page.